# Transforming a function to use method of residues

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I have an integral

$$I=\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\dfrac{d^3\textbf{k}}{(k^2+\gamma)^2}$$

where $\gamma$ is independent of k. $d^3\textbf{k}$ is given as the 3 components of a vector. I am asked to evaluate this integral in spherical coordinates using the method of residues and achieve the result $\frac{\pi^2}{\sqrt{\gamma}}$. My issue is transforming this integral into a function on the complex plane to use the method of residues on. I contemplated maybe cubing a one dimensional portion of the integral, but the order of the pole becomes "non-integer" for each piece and are then not helpful in my case. Any suggestions?

Comment: First do the angular integrals (they are trivial). The radial piece can then be done by a standard residue calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand is spherically symmetric, so you can change to spherical coordinates,
$$\mathbf{k} = r(\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta},\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta},\cos{\theta}).$$
Then the Jacobian is $r^2 \sin{\theta} $, and your integral becomes
$$ I = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{r^2}{(r^2 + \gamma)^2} \int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \sin{\theta} \, d\phi \, d\theta \, dr = 4\pi \int_0^{\infty} \frac{r^2 \, dr}{(r^2 + \gamma)^2} $$
At this point it probably wants you to extend to the whole real line by using that the integrand is even,
$$ I = 2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{r^2 \, dr}{(r^2 + \gamma)^2}, $$
and then use a semicircle contour and go and find the residue at $i\sqrt{\gamma}$, for example.

(Remark: Not the best way to finish this integral if you know about the Gamma function and the Gaussian integral: you can write the denominator as $ \int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x(r^2+\alpha)} \, dx $, interchange the order of integration and go from there.)

Comment: Ah cool. Thank you. I was thinking about this the wrong way, I was sort of obsessed with this other way of solving these types of integrals, but this way makes way more sense.